# Database Schema, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, multi-select

I have the `mysql tables`

```
Contract
-**contract_id** (PRIMARY)

Contract_to_groups
-**group_id** (PRIMARY)
-contract_id

Groups_to_users
-group_id
-user_id
```

I have this multiselect(`multiselect.js`) where elem is the users

[image]
I have already the contract and I want to create a group of users. So I select my users from `multiselect`and then click `submit`. `On submit` in my table `Groups_to_users` should be saved the users I selected from the multiselect.

I have the problem that if I set in `Contract_to_groups` the `group_id` as AUTO_INCREMENT I cannot save in `Groups_to_users` the users for this group because I dont know the `group_id` of `Contract_to_groups`, it is AUTO_INCREMENT and especially if I have four(4) multiselects and each with users how can I save in these two(2) tables `Contract_to_groups, Groups_to_users` the data with the correct `ids` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your `Contract_to_groups` table, and add an `id` which wil be the auto incrementing primary key:

```
-**id** (PRIMARY)
-group_id 
-contract_id
```

Comment: Yeah but the think is now how when I click submit I will save the group_id in Contract_to_groups and then in Groups_to_users the group_id again. If I have as I say four(4) multiselect how this can be done for all of them ?? It a bit complex

Comment: And at the same time I have a lot of contracts, and group_ids at Contract_to_groups must not be the same

Comment: Maybe you should have more tables (4 or 5): Contracts(**contract_id** (PRIMARY)),Groups(**group_id** (PRIMARY)), Groups_to_users (**gtu_id** (PRIMARY), group_id, user_id), Contract_to_groups (**ctg_id** (PRIMARY), group_id (UNIQUE), contract_id), & (optional) Users(**user_id** (PRIMARY)). When populating the tables with data from multiselect, you have to carefully watch the order of tables. As the Contract table is already populated, you have to insert the group_id in the Groups table first,first & after that the values in Groups_to_users & Contract_to_groups.

Comment: In order to ensure the insertion of values in all required tables, you have to put all queries in a single transaction. So, if the inserting of even one value fails, no data will be inserted anywhere.